# Shiny / Flex-dashboard Reactive Polygon Creation

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf, flexdashboard

This might be one for the GIS board, but any help is appreciated. I suspect it is a lack of knowledge around how Shiny works in flex dashboard. I have a map that will take a lat/ and long point (as numeric inputs) create a radius circle, then intersect that circle with UK LSOA's (our smallest official polygon geographic unit). The final map then returns three layers: `the lat long point of origin`, `The radius circle polygon`, `LSOA polygons intersecting the circle`. So this map takes three inputs: `radius`,`lat` and `long`, all of which are numeric.

My errors are around calling reactive objects into subsequent functions. Here is an exmaple; `Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"`

So what I am doing wrong? Here is the current code

```
#Package Call
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(flexclust)
library(swfscMisc)
library(reactable)

#Prams
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

radius<-0.5
```

```
numericInput("dub_lon",label = h3("Longitude"),value=-0.080216)

numericInput("dub_lat",label = h3("Longitude"),value=51.500058)
```

```
#Ploygons

polys <- reactive({as.data.frame(circle.polygon(input$dub_lon, input$dub_lat, radius, poly.type = "gc.earth"))%>%
            t_as_sf(., coords=c("lon","lat"))%>% 
  dplyr::summarise() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")%>%
  st_convex_hull()%>%
  st_set_crs(., 4269)})
```

```
#Get LSOA's

ukmap <- st_read("Lower_Super_Output_Area_(LSOA)_IMD2019__(WGS84)/Lower_Super_Output_Area_(LSOA)_IMD2019__(WGS84).shp")

ukmap_sub_pro<-st_transform(ukmap,4269)

X<- st_intersection(polys,ukmap_sub_pro)

filter_ukmap<-ukmap_sub_pro[ukmap_sub_pro$lsoa11cd %in% unique(X$lsoa11cd), ]
```

Note: I have removed the reactive bits from this, but tried them in many configurations. Also radius is fixed at the moment just to make it easier on me, but if a method works I will swap it.

Any help, as always is appreciated!

Comment: Try with `st_intersection(polys(), ukmap_sub_pro)`. A reactive behaves like a function so you have to access it's values by calling like a function, i.e. `polys()`.

Comment: No dice unfortunately, changing it too `polys()` gives the following: `Error: Operation not allowed with active reactive context. You tired to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer` So I think the reactive bit needs to go father back. Or, try to wrap the entire polygon and polygon intersection in reactive?